# select from normalized tables using external references

Tags: postgresql, select, foreign-keys, normalization

I am trying to create a normalized set of tables for my books and then
to select them ordering by either book title or authors.
I want to be able to have 'n' books per author, and 'n' authors per book.

The problem I want to solve is how to display my books and authors
ordered by tile or by `lastname,firstname,middlename`?

I started with a table like this with some 1441 entries.

```
create table books(
bookid serial,
title text,
firstname text,
lastname text);
```

I then created an authors table

```
create table authors(
authorid serial,
firstname text,
lastname text);
```

and populated it.

I then created a cross reference table

```
create table bookAuthor
(    
     bookId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES books(bookId),
     authorId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES authors(authorId)
);
```

and

```
create unique index bookAuthor_unique_index on bookAuthor(bookId, authorId);
```

I then populated the bookauthor table with 1441 entries.

I am pretty sure the three tables are populated correctly.  I managed to
do several inserts into the authors table and then insert the correct cross relationshipes into the bookauthor table.

I am now stuck, I can't figure out how to display my books and authors
ordered by title or by authors names.

Am I going down the wrong path to create this ability to create N titles per author and N authors per book.

I did multiple searches for foreign keys, and multiple tables with nothing that seemed to resolve my problem.

I'm in a postgresql 9.x environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join will be helpful.

```
select * from bookAuthor
inner join books on bookAuthor.bookId = books.bookid
inner join authors on bookAuthor.authorId = authors.authorid
order by books.title;
```

Or you can order by `authors.lastname, authors.firstname` instead.

Comment: ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 3: inner join books on bookAuthor.bookId shucks I can't figure out how to format this reply..

Comment: I just edited the query as I forgot to actually join the columns on anything.  Are you running this in an sql editor or via a programming language?  That error you're receiving is foreign to me.

Comment: Test formating response ... `# select *  from bookAuthor inner join books on bookAuthor.bookId inner join authors on bookAuthor.authorId order by books.title ;`  Caused the following error message  `ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: select *  from bookAuthor inner join books on bookAuthor.boo...
`

Comment: user258812, I was using psql to test your solution.  Thanks for your response.  Hmmm I just tried your updated solution  :)  it seems to be producing an output now.  I tried `select * from bookAuthor
inner join books on bookAuthor.bookId = books.bookid
inner join authors on bookAuthor.authorId = authors.authorid and authors.lastname='Patterson'
order by books.lastname limit 3;
`  that worked.

Comment: Yes!  I found a book by James Patterson with a 2nd author, added the 2nd author to the authors table, and added the cross links to the bookauthor table, then did a select and it got it right !!!!! supercalifradglisticexpidalocious !!!  I have been struggling with this for the better part of a week before posting here. I got both selects to work ( order by title, and order by author ).  Thank you ever so much.  Now on to trying to figure out how to make this work in my PHP code.  And how to prevent adding a duplicate author / misspelled